# How to get value of cell only if it is not containing any number ? - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac, microsoft-excel-2013

I'm using Excel version `15.27` on Mac and I want to get value from first column cells (A) and adding it to the last column cells (D) only if the cell from column A doesn't contains any number .

For example in column A :

`plan/3432` >> Don't take this value

`343343` >> Don't take this value

`Neighborhood Name` >> Take this value

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data in column **A**, in **D1** enter the formula:

```
=IF(COUNT(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},A1))>0,"",A1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Any **A** cells containing numerals will not appear in column **D**.